# Microsoft Graph Explorer consent screen is giving wrong scopes

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

When I try to login for the first time with new user via active directory to graphexplorer.windowsazure.net I get following scopes:

[image]

In my apps.dev.microsoft.com I have following permissions:
[image]

Why am I getting only these two scopes in access token:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apps registered via the [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com) use the **Azure AD v2 endpoint which supports incremental consent**.

This means that while your app registration determines which scopes can be requested, **you still need to specify specific scopes when you make the authorize request**. Also, you should avoid requesting all scopes up front, rather incrementally request scopes as needed in the context of specific operations. So start out with your authorize request as you have it, with no extra scopes but when you need to send an email on behalf of the user issue another authorize request like so:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
    client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
    &response_type=code
    &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
    &response_mode=query
    &scope=
    https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.send
    &state=12345
```

For more info on scopes in the v2.0 endpoint check out the [*Scopes, permissions, and consent in the Azure Active Directory v2.0 endpoint* document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes).

For an example of an app that incrementally requests scopes, check out this [*Integrate Microsoft identity and the Microsoft Graph into a web application using OpenID Connect* sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-v2/).

Comment: Thanks but this is via graphexplorer where I am looking up the api... so I need all scopes. I am not running client NBC or something it's graphexplorer.

Comment: I think you're mixing up things. the GraphExplorer already has a app registration which you don't see nor control in apps.dev.microsoft.com. GraphExplorer uses Directory.AccessAsUser not any individual permissions.

Comment: Whereas the screenshot from apps.dev.microsoft.com is for some other app for which you do control permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that there 2 different Graph APIs:

- **Azure AD Graph** (endpoint: **graph.windows.net**, explorer: https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/)
- **Microsoft Graph** (Endpoint: **graph.microsoft.com**, Explorer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api:

*We strongly recommend that you use Microsoft Graph instead of Azure AD Graph API to access Azure Active Directory resources. Our development efforts are now concentrated on Microsoft Graph and no further enhancements are planned for Azure AD Graph API. There are a very limited number of scenarios for which Azure AD Graph API might still be appropriate; for more information, see the Microsoft Graph or the Azure AD Graph blog post in the Office Dev Center.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure where that screen shot is coming from, but the URL you're going to is incorrect. The correct URL for Graph Explorer is https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer.